# Accessing model variable from gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a table Employee in the db with columns like say emp id, emp name and emp address and emp phone number(This field can be more than one and is a unique id) and according to the no. of phone number's provided , the no. of row's for that emp id can increase as well.
Table something like the below:

```
Emp Id  Emp Name    Emp Address     Emp Phone
10001   Jack        abc             70102938
10001   Jack        abc             39876538
10002   Jim         xyz             23492020
```

I have my gsp in which I would like to display a particular panel only if emp phone is present or else it should be hidden completely, something like

```
<div class="subbody  ${someBean?.aCondition ? 'shownItem':'hiddenItem'}">
```

with the css

```
.shownItem{
        display: block;
    }
    .hiddenItem{
        display: none;
    }
```

What I am not getting is how do I write that condition in the gsp  `${someBean?.aCondition ?`

Comment: how your domain classes looks like ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<g:if>` instead:

```
<g:if test="${someBean?.aCondition}">
     Whatever you want to display
</g:if>
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/if.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have passed your `someBean` correctly from your controller, and assuming the property of that Domain object is called `empPhone` something like this should work:

`<div class="subbody  ${(someBean?.empPhone != null) ? 'shownItem':'hiddenItem'}">`

As a side note I think you should consider refactoring your domain model and normalize your database by creating a `Phone` domain object that is linked to `Employee` via a one-to-many relationship.